# Comparison X.N.A & W.P.F

Tags: c#, wpf, xna

I have designed an interface for Windows. I want to develop it.

Instead of writing a shell for Windows which will require me to learn a lot and a lot and a lot more new things i am thinking about making a Full Screen App which will run on windows and users will only be able to interact through this app. I think Microsoft Surface does the same.

So i was looking at my options, i have decided to do this in managed code, C# cuz that's where my expertise lie and the development will be easy.

After that i need to choose from **WPF** or **XNA**, hold on let me explain XNA. I don't know WPF yet so i don't know it's power but i was thinking if i was to put some "Intensive Graphics" for my interface, with XNA it will be really easy cuz i can use "Particle System" and stuff. If you have worked with XNA you would know what i mean, create interfaces in 2D and all, while using the power of XNA.

The other option is WPF, which i don't know, therefore, i can't make a decision myself.

So, people who know WPF & preferable XNA as well.

Why i shouldn't be using "C# + XNA", what disadvantages will be there and where will this combination fail.

Why should i be using WPF or is WPF going to be good-enough Graphics-wise i mean like animating anything, i literally mean anything etc etc.

p.s

I know i will have to select one answer but all the answers will be a very beneficial discussion for me.

Comment: Your question is far too vague. Please try to ask something specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a games programmer myself I found a transition to WPF to be very challenging. Still, it is miles ahead of XNA in terms of GUI design. If your application (which you should really tell us more about) relies on GUI for user interaction, you would have to create an entire GUI system from the ground up in XNA. That does not sound fun to me.

WPF has some rich media access. You can perform render transforms on controls. There is also a Viewport3D object which allows you to render 3d objects. A quick Google search also turned up a [particle engine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21010/Particle-Effects-in-WPF), though I can't verify the effectiveness of it.

Basically, if you're writing a GUI application, use WPF and learn how to adapt it for your purposes. Don't force yourself to write an entire GUI/page system in XNA. That's not what XNA is meant to do, and I know from minimal experience of writing GUI functions for my games that it's just a major pain.

Answer (score 1):

XNA and WPF are fundamentally different technologies so you need to pick the one that suits your situation. XNA is geared toward the game developer, while WPF is for application development.

Do you need to utilize the graphics card? Need to write a game for Xbox 360? Choose XNA.

Do you need to make a desktop application that lets users view and edit data? This includes Web browser, media player, word processor, etc. Choose WPF.

Comment: :) There is no hard line to separate games and apps. Both XNA and WPF utilize your graphic cards heavily.

Comment: Link for previous comment, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms742196.aspx.  However, I would add that the fundamental way each technology is designed is correct in this answer.

Comment: @LexLi You are quite right. My point is just you should pick the tool that was designed for the job at hand. XNA is geared toward games, so IMHO it shouldn't be squished into anything else. And the same for WPF (or any other technology).

Answer (score 0):

I think for your situation, XNA might be a better way to go (though WPF should provide similar support), as XNA goes to more platforms than WPF.

Via MonoGame (http://monogame.codeplex.com), XNA based applications can be running on iOS, Android, OS X, Linux, and much more.

Comment: cross platform is not important cuz i will be making a lot and lot and a lot more Windows API Calls...